# Интерфейс Closeable и идемпотентность

Tags: java

Пытаясь разобраться в разнице между интерфейсами *AutoCloseable* и *Closeable*, я узнал, что метод `close()` в *AutoCloseable* не обязан быть идемпотентным, а в *Closeable* обязан.

из документации:

```
Note that unlike the close method of Closeable, this close method is not required to be
idempotent. In other words, calling this close method more than once may have some visible
side effect, unlike Closeable.close which is required to have no effect if called more than once.
```

Как видно из документации, идемпотентность в данном случае означает, что вызов метод более чем одного раза не даёт никаких побочных эффектов.

Так вот, я никак не могу понять каким способом, в данном случае, можно обязать метод быть идемпотентным. В моём представлении, это можно организовать лишь при помощи определения метода, который мы опишем таким образом, что он будет гарантировать идемпотентность. Но в данном случае *Closeable*, чей метод `close()` обязан быть идемпотентным, лишь интерфейс, который не предоставляют данный метод по умолчанию.

Comment: Есть спор https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141302/implements-closeable-or-implements-autocloseable. Можете почитать информацию там.

Comment: От себя лично добавлю: AutoClosable может применяться в более общих контексках, чем Closable из-за того, что AutoClosable бросает Exception, а Closable бросает IOException. Идеология try-with-resources подразумевает работу с ресурсами. И получается: мы работаем с ресурсами и для этого есть IOException, почему тогда AutoClosable бросает просто Exception?

Comment: В моём понимании идемпотнентность интерфейса Closable в том, что любое исключение в нём если и даст ошибка, то ошибка будет связана с ресурсами, чем обуславливается идемпотненость. А интерфейс AutoClosable может дать абсолютно любой результат.